# Difference between nameof and typeof

Tags: c#, built-in, typeof, c#-6.0, nameof

Correct me if I am wrong, but doing something like

```
var typeOfName = typeof(Foo).Name;
```

and

```
var nameOfName = nameof(Foo);
```

should give you exactly the same output. One of the understandable reasons according to this source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx is that

> "Using nameof helps keep your code valid when renaming definitions"

If you want to get the class instance as string it is **not** possible to do something like that:

```
var fooInstance = new Foo();
var nameOfName = nameof(fooInstance);
```

however, you can do something like:

```
static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class 
{
  return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
}
var typeOfName2 = GetName(new { fooInstance });
```

In both cases (`typeof` and `nameof`) a refactoring is possible, so I dont see any other reason for reinventing another higher level keyword, such as `nameof`, to perform something that already exists. Are there any differences between them that I don't clearly see?

Finally, I would appreciate if could someone point me to a reference source to have a look at the implementation of `nameof`. Does it use Reflection?

**Update 1:**
Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573102/is-nameof-evaluated-at-compile-time)

`nameof` is apparently as efficient as declaring a string variable. No reflection or whatsoever!

```
var firstname = "Gigi";
 var varname = nameof(firstname);
 Console.WriteLine(varname); // Prints "firstname" to the console
```

When you check out the MSIL generated you will see that it is equivalent to a string declaration because an object reference to a string gets pushed to the stack using the ldstr operator:

```
IL_0001: ldstr "Gigi"
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldstr "firstname"
IL_000c: stloc.1
IL_000d: ldloc.1
IL_000e: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Comment: `nameof(fooInstance)` returns `"fooInstance"`. With `nameof` you get the name of the variable, not the name of the type.

Comment: it gets the string version of it's variable.
nameof(aaa) will return "aaa"

Comment: `static string GetName<T>(T item)` does something completely different than `typeof` or `nameof`. It returns the name of a random property the Type has. It could also throw an exception if it's used in a different way than intended.

Comment: I'd rather use `nameof` than add my own method with anonymous types.

Comment: `nameof` and `typeof` are not functions

Comment: I meant they are compile time features, hence you'll not see a "reference source implementation". Your examples are run time functions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Two reasons:

`nameof` turns into a compile-time constant. `typeof(...).Name` requires a bit of reflection. It's not *overly* expensive, but it can hurt in some cases.

Second, it's used for other things than type names. For example, arguments:

```
void SomeMethod(int myArgument)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(nameof(myArgument));
}
```

You can also get the name of class members and even locals. Needless to say, this is quite useful for debugging information. It's also one of the ways to implement less fragile reflection when e.g. parsing expression trees (sadly, on the project where I'd use this, we're still stuck on .NET 4.0 with C# 5 - it'd save me a few hacks here and there).

And to clear up some confusion, `nameof` is *not* a function, and neither is `typeof`. It's a compile-time operator, and it's always evaluated at compile-time  (though obviously, generics move the "compile-time" a bit further in time).

Answer (score 21):

Here's a benchmark test by using BenchmarkDotNet

```
// * Summary *

Host Process Environment Information:
BenchmarkDotNet.Core=v0.9.9.0
OS=Windows
Processor=?, ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=2740584 ticks, Resolution=364.8857 ns, Timer=TSC
CLR=CORE, Arch=64-bit ? [RyuJIT]
GC=Concurrent Workstation
dotnet cli version: 1.0.0-preview2-003133

Type=GetNameBenchmark  Mode=Throughput  LaunchCount=2
WarmupCount=10  TargetCount=200

     Method |     Median |    StdDev |
----------- |----------- |---------- |
     TypeOf | 16.0348 ns | 0.7896 ns |
     NameOf |  0.0005 ns | 0.0147 ns |
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out BenchmarkDotNet ... never heard of it before

Answer (score 12):

Using Reflection to generate strings is possible, but is not very elegant and not always possible.  You can't use Reflection in sandboxed code for example.  And you can't use it on local variables.  And it is expensive.

The `nameof` operator works at compile time.  The compiler already knows the name when it parses the code.  So can trivially generate the string literal.  Very fast, can't possibly be faster, and no runtime restrictions.

Answer (score 6):

There are several differences between them, but they are mainly practical reasons behind. 
**Example 1:**

It is more elegant to write something like

```
switch (e.ArgumentPropertyName)
{
    case nameof(aProperty):
    break;

    case "anotherProperty":
    break;
}
```

Try to refactor `anotherProperty` type and bang! the `nameof` will reflect the changes, the `"anotherProperty"` will pass silently and your code will never get executed within that case statement..

**Example 2:**

```
enum MetalEnum { Gold = 1,  Silver = 2, ... }
```

Which one is nicer?

```
Console.WriteLine(MetalEnum.Gold.ToString()); // finds the name at runtime (slower)
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(MetalEnum.Gold)); // compile time (faster)
```

**Example 3:**

Finally, do you remember how ugly it is to write something like

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
```

Now you can write as beautifully as follows:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Foo)));
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn986596):

> Used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable, type, or member.
>
> ...
>
> The argument to **nameof** must be a simple name, qualified name, member access, base access with a specified member, or this access with a specified member. The argument expression identifies a code definition, but it is never evaluated.
>
> Because the argument needs to be an expression syntactically, there are many things disallowed that are not useful to list. The following are worth mentioning that produce errors: predefined types (for example, **int** or **void**), nullable types (`Point?`), array types (`Customer[,]`), pointer types (`Buffer*`), qualified alias (`A::B`), and unbound generic types (`Dictionary<,>`), preprocessing symbols (`DEBUG`), and labels (`loop:`).

The simple name that **nameof** obtains is the source name, not the metadata name.

So, this code:

```
using Integer = System.Int32;
var s = "a string";
Console.WriteLine(nameof(s));
Console.WriteLine(nameof(Integer));
Console.WriteLine(nameof(System.Int32));
void M<T>() { Console.WriteLine(nameof(T)); }
M<int>();
M<string>();
```

will print:

```
s
Integer
Int32
T
T
```

Answer (score 3):

**Typeof** returns Type objects. It is often used as a parameter or as a variable or field. The typeof operator is part of an expression that acquires the Type pointer.

```
class Program
{
    static Type _type = typeof(char); // Store Type as field.

    static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(_type); // Value type pointer
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(int)); // Value type
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(byte)); // Value type
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Stream)); // Class type
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(TextWriter)); // Class type
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Array)); // Class type
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(int[])); // Array reference type
    }
}
```

Output

```
System.Char
System.Int32
System.Byte
System.IO.Stream
System.IO.TextWriter
System.Array
System.Int32[]
```

**Nameof**, meanwhile, returns a string with a variable's name. It works at compile-time. It is a special compiler feature that simplifies some programs.

```
int size=100;
Console.WriteLine(nameof(size));
```

**output**:size

Answer (score 0):

Typeof returns Type objects. It is often used as a parameter or as a variable or field. The typeof operator is part of an expression that acquires the Type pointer.

Nameof, meanwhile, returns a string with a variable's name. It works at compile-time. It is a special compiler feature that simplifies some programs.