# nameof won´t reflect using

Tags: c#, using, nameof

I have an alias within my source-code file like this:

MyClass.cs

```
using System;               
using SomeClass = NewClass;
    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(SomeClass));
    }
}
public class NewClass { }
```

I need this because the names of my classes changed and now I need to compile for both the old and the new class-structure symultaneously.

When I run that code I get `"SomeClass"` but I' d expected `"NewClass"`. Why doesn't `nameof` reflect the alias using the `using`-directive in this case?

Comment: [By design](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1173546/nameoftypealias-should-return-type-name-instead-of.html)?

Comment: It strikes me that this is one of those situations where you can't always get what you want because as many people would expect it to reflect `SomeClass` as would expect `NewClass`.

Comment: @Sinatr Yeap, seems so. Thanks for the link

Comment: Note that `string str1 = nameof(System)` works, so `nameof` works even on things like namespaces, and `using K = System; string str2 = nameof(K)` will return `K`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe you´re right. I hoped I can **avoid** naming-confusions within my code-migration project using `nameof`. However it seems I´m **causing** them instead.

Comment: "I need this because the names of my classes changed and now I need to compile for both the old and the new class-structure symultaneously."   Sounds exactly like a use case for the adapter pattern to me.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern .  Especially if the business logic of the two systems is different.  Maybe I'm missing some context though ;)

Comment: @DanRayson No, the BL keeps the same, only the names of the classes change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `nameof` keyword is meant to "get the name of an identifier", without evaluating its value or anything else, like said in docs:

> A nameof expression is evaluated at compile time and has no effect at run time.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Comment: But because it **is** a compile-time constant I´d expected the `using` which is also evaluated at compile-time to be reflected.

Comment: Yes, one can expect it to behave like that, but unfortunately, as it is designed it gets its constant value before anything else on compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question was "why doesn't it?" but, here's a "what can do it instead?" answer for you :)

Use `typeof` instead of `nameof`.

```
using System;               
using SomeClass = NewClass;
    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(SomeClass));
    }   
}

public class NewClass { }
```

prints

```
NewClass
```

Comment: It's [not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33649501/1997232), `typeof` is slower and usage is more limited.

Comment: @Sinatr That's why it does different things o_0  It does what he wanted, I thought?  I don't understand what your criticism is getting at?

Comment: No critisim, just a comment for whoever reads the answer.

Comment: Oooooh, I understand now xD  Took me a while.