# Printing the name of a variable with nameOf that references another variable?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have multiple instances of a class that I would like to track within an array that holds this type of class that I do not control. To do so I have created a `List<MyClass>` that I then compare to each value in the `MyClass[]` that I do not control.

I then print out the name of the class references with the C#6.0 operator `nameOf`. To my surprise (well its obvious now why) when I go to print the name of the class references when checking it from the `List` the loop variable name is printed instead of the class reference it references.

**Is there a way to print the name of a variable that is referenced by another variable?**

(*Also what is the proper jargon to use for this question, I feel like I butchered it?*)

---

Here is an example of the issue using `Control`

```
Control x = new Control();
Control y = new Control();
Control z = new Control();
var controlArr = new Control[] { x, y, z };
var controlList = new List<Control>() { x, y, z };
for (int i = 0; i < controlArr.Length; i++)
{
    Control anArrControl = controlArr[i];
    foreach (var aListControl in controlList)
        if (anArrControl == aListControl)
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Control[" + i + "]: " + nameof(aListControl));
}
```

This code will print

```
Control[0]: aListControl 
Control[1]: aListControl 
Control[2]: aListControl
```

Instead of

```
Control[0]: x
Control[1]: y
Control[2]: z
```

**EDIT:** This example is simple in that if the `Control[]` does not contain a reference in the `List<Control>` nothing will be printed. In my actual application I take care of this. I simply put the example code to demonstrate what I mean when I asked the question, I didn't feel as if I worded it properly.

Comment: No. Think about what would happen if instead of `{ x, y, z }`, you initialized the collection with `{ x, y, new Control() }`. What would you expect it to print?

Comment: no, that's not possible.  At that point `x` and `Control[i]` are just pointing to the same object.

Comment: It does not work this way. `nameof` is evaluated at compile time, in fact by "expressing its argument as a literal": see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573102/is-nameof-evaluated-at-compile-time?rq=1)

Comment: I agree with the compile time comment, that's probably the most important thing to realize here

Comment: Name does not exist. Only address. Even when you use nameof that string is ready in compile time not after you run your program

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a `Dictionary<string, Control>`.

Comment: idea: take the `nameof`s of the original array members as you declare them, and take them along in a `Tuple<Control,string>`. Ugly but might work.

Comment: You are using nameof(aListControl)), thats why its giving correct value. If you do nameof(aListControl[i]) then it will give you x,y,z

Comment: @viveknuna This will not work, you will get an error "Expression does not have a name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn986596.aspx) you find a reference of use cases that motivated the creation of the nameof function. The name of a reference is not defined at compile time. Given

```
 var a = new object();
 var b = a;
 var array = new [] {a, b}
```

What should `nameof(array[1])` return ? It is the same referenced object.

Therefore you have to think of another workaround to achieve your goal. Perhaps a Dictionary might help you. Like

```
Control x = new Control();
Control y = new Control();
Control z = new Control();
var references = new Dictionary<Control, string> {
    { x, "x" }, { y, "y" }, {z, "z"}
};
var controlArr = new Control[] { x, y, z };
var controlList = new List<Control>() { x, y, z };
for (int i = 0; i < controlArr.Length; i++)
{
    Control anArrControl = controlArr[i];
    foreach (var aListControl in controlList)
        if (anArrControl == aListControl)
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Control[" + i + "]: " + references[aListControl]);
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be basically the only option (You could also just use `nameOf(x)` instead of the literal string too!). Thanks rboe!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that won't work, since controlList does not contain x, y and z - it contains the controls that x, y and z refered to at the time of assignment.

There are two alternatives that you might want to consider:

1. Store the control *and its variable name* in a `List<Tuple<Control, String>>`:

   ```
   var controlList = new[] {
       Tuple.Create(x, nameof(x)),
       Tuple.Create(y, nameof(y)),
       Tuple.Create(z, nameof(z))
   }.ToList();
   ```

   Obviously, your comparison then needs to be changed to `anArrControl == aListControl.Item1`.
2. Some classes (such as [WinForm's `Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx)) have a `Name` property. Maybe that name suits your purpose as well?