# nameof with casting

Tags: c#, casting, nameof

I want to use nameof in order to get the name of a property.

**The following work:**

```
DerivedClass EC = baseClassObj as DerivedClass;
nameof(EC.propertyX)
```

**but this doesn't work:**

```
nameof((baseClassObj as DerivedClass).propertyX)
```

with the compile error of:

```
Sub-expression cannot be used in an argument to nameof
```

BTW, also this doesn't work:

```
nameof(((baseClassObj)DerivedClass).propertyX)
```

**Can someone explain this casting + nameof problem?**

Comment: There is no other explanation than finding the language specification for you or looking at the documentation. It's simply not supported.

Comment: The error explains it all. No sub-expressions are allowed as arguments to `nameof`. Try storing `(baseClassObj as DerivedClass)` into a variable, and use that in the nameof argument.

Comment: As RATM used to say : "Casting then the nameof". And now you do what they told ya

Comment: It's the same reason why you can not use every expression you want in a constant: the compiler needs to be able to evaluate the expression at compile time. That means you are restricted to operations the compiler can actually do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is nameof() evaluated at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573102/is-nameof-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 4):

nameof is a compile time thing and therefore static. To get what you want, just use nameof(DerivedClass.PropertyX):

```
class BaseClass
{
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyX { get; set; }
}

static class UsePropertyName
{
    public static string GetPropertyName(BaseClass classInstance)
    {
        //Instance not actually used.
        return nameof(DerivedClass.PropertyX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nameof works basically as a preprocessed macro. Before compile time it will be replaced by the actual name of the parameter, from there on it is like a "constant string" in the assembly.

`The argument expression identifies a code definition, but it is never evaluated.`
see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the `nameof()` works with reflection based on the expression provided in `nameof()`. Therefore, the engine obviously has problems to "decompile" the expression if it's not "simple expression".

You might be interested in creating some extension method that will take `baseClassObj as DerivedClass` as parameter and return the result of `nameof()`.

EDIT: `nameof()` is evaluated in compile time, that's the main reason :)

Comment: `nameof` has absolutely nothig to do with reflection. It is a pure compile time feature while reflection occurs at runtime.